# Automatically login to Mac even when using Apple ID as Mac account password

Tags: macos, mac, apple-id, password, login

I use my Apple ID as my Mac's account password, so now I can't enable auto-login. Is there really no way to re-enable auto-login even if I'm using my Apple ID for my Mac account? Or is there something I can do to re-enable auto-login again so I don't have to type my password in every time I start up my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mavericks then open syst pref users and select the log in options.

[image: log in]

Now you can select the Auto log in off or User name.

Comment: The "Automatic login" field is disabled and defaults to "Off" when I choose to link my Mac's user account with my Apple ID, though, so I can't do this.

Comment: do you see the lock? unlock it first.

Comment: I already unlocked it. I used to be able to use the dropdown, but after changing to using Apple ID, it is disabled. This is a feature and not a bug, as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it. In Auto log in drop down you have OFF or users names (regardless of what it is), there is no choice for AppleID unless you made your self as User name same as AppleID. You can choose any user name.

Comment: In OS X Yosemite, you can choose to link your Mac's user account to your Apple ID, therefore using your Apple ID to login to that user account. That's what I did, and after doing that, the "Auto login" dropdown box is disabled, and is set to OFF.

Comment: I was not aware you are on Yosemite! in your case, are you sure the AppleID is the same as that users?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't be able to login to my Mac account.

Comment: I was talking about the information you entered in the Security&privacy  Auto log in as + Password info.

Comment: That's the same password as my account password, according to the menus I see on that page.

Answer (score 1):

The anwser is.. **YOU CAN'T**.  @user133639 *tried* to spit it out, but the solution is to use a SEPERATE, **local** password (i.e. not just your iCloud credentials).  After you set this up, you will again be able to choose your account as "it" for `Auto-Login`.  Peace!

Answer (score 0):

You have to not use your iCloud account as your password.  Select change password under the user & groups, then select use a separate password.  It will work then.  It was disabled in Yosemite as a security feature I believe if coupled with your iCloud account password.